# jQuery .on() Not Working After Different Content Loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you go to http://www.elemovements.com and try clicking "Read more..." on the first article, it will work, along with if you click the same link in the archive.  This is all taken care of by this block of code... it's messy, yes, but I've been trying to figure various ways of doing it.

```js
( function() {

    var $Body = $("#news .inner");
    var $Title = $("#news .title");

    var strNewsURL = "<?=URL_NEWS?>";

    $(document).on("click", "a:contains(Read More...)", function(event) {

        var strOld = $Body.html();
        var strURL = $(this).attr("href").replace("index.php", strNewsURL);

        //var strBackURL = strURL.match(/archive.php/) ? "archive.php?xnewsaction=getnews&newsarch=" + getURLVars(strURL)['newsarch'] : strNewsURL;

        $Body.slideUp(100);

        $.get(

            strURL,

            objNHF,

            function(strData) {

                $Body.html(strData + '<a class="back"><?=TEXT_BACK?></a>').slideDown(1000, "easeOutBounce");

                $(document).on("click", "#news a.back", function(event) {

                    $Body.slideUp(100, function() {

                        $(this).html(strOld);

                    } ).slideDown(1000, "easeOutBounce");;

                    event.preventDefault();

                } );

            }

        );

        track(strURL);

        event.preventDefault();

    } );

} )();
```

If you try loading another page (let's say, "Contact"), then click "Home" again, the event fires but does not load the content into the div.  What am I doing wrong here?  Very puzzling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These variables are declared outside of your `on/live` click.  When the new content is loaded, these elements are replaced and the variables point to the old copy.

```
var $Body = $("#news .inner");
var $Title = $("#news .title");
```

Move these variables inside the click so they are refreshed each time:

```
$(document).on("click", "a:contains(Read More...)", function(event) {

    var $Body = $("#news .inner");
    var $Title = $("#news .title");
...
```

Comment: **I was just trying to post that at the same time!**  Haha.  Unfortunately, my reputation doesn't allow me to answer my own questions yet, so, hooray for you.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: However, I am also experiencing a new problem (ugh).  Not that a user would ever do this, but if you click "Read More..." more than once, and hit "<< Back" on the second or higher run, the content slides down the amount of times you have been there.  The event definitely fires increasingly.  Anyone?

Comment: Ah, that's because the `a.back` handler should be a simple `click()`, not `on()`.  Thanks, everyone.

Comment: I can only see one item with "Read More..." on the site linked in the original question.  Maybe I'm not understanding what you mean.

Comment: Refer to my next comment.  I meant if you browsed between the "Read More..." area, clicked "<< Back," then clicked the **same** "Read More..." link again.  It's all good now.  Thanks, man.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use pseudo selectors for a delegated event handler. To fix this just use the HTML structure around the links to your advantage:

```
$(document).on('click', '.more a', function () {...});
```

This is a good idea anyway because the `:contains` pseudo-selector is quite slow. `a:contains(Read More...)` has to iterate through every link on the page and get it's text to check against.

Comment: What's puzzling is it's running fine at first, but if I change the content of the same div where the #news div is, then reload the #news div, it won't work.

Comment: I just tried adding a span around the link with that class name, attached the event, and still, I am experiencing the same issue.  While I agree this method is a bit more logical, it's a news system that I plugged in and I didn't feel like going through thousands of lines of code to modify its HTML.  This was just a prototype anyway because it's the first instance of such a link on this site.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is null

http://jsfiddle.net/qRWa5/21/

Comment: If s/he's using `on()` then s/he's using jQuery 1.7+, in which versions `live()` is deprecated (and `on()` is recommended). Prior to version 1.7 `delegate()` is preferred.

Comment: good point. but on() is not working as expected, and live() would.

Comment: I've tried live() as well but that seemed to fail.  It looked as though on() replaced live()?  Here's a jsFiddle to demonstrate the same idea: http://jsfiddle.net/grn2012/qRWa5/20/

Comment: I am reloading a div with id `news` with a div of class `inner` inside it on the actual page.  That fiddle was a poor example.  Reference the actual site and follow these steps: 1) Click "Read More..." to show it actually works.  2) Click **Contact** or some other link besides **Home**.  3) Go back to home and click the "Read More..." link again.

Comment: I guess I should say, `on()` is working but `html()` does not replace the content.

Comment: I have made a discovery! On your site, the 'on' is infact working! The $.get triggers on each additional click, even when its not loading to the dom.

Comment: what files does this script live in on your site?